# ExpressJS - POST Router returns 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest, express

I am pretty new to ExpressJS and just setting up a small todo list app in combination with React. I do already get my list of todos from a mysql database but am struggling with the POST request to update/insert into the database.

When I am calling http://localhost:9000/api/v1/todos/get, the router is working well and returning the expected value. When I call http://localhost:9000/api/v1/todos/add, I am always getting a 404.

**app.js**

```
let createError = require('http-errors');
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let logger = require('morgan');
let cors = require("cors");

let indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
let todosRouter = require('./routes/api/v1/todos');

let app = express();
app.use(cors());

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/todos', todosRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**todos.js**

```
let express    = require("express");
let router     = express.Router();
let config     = require("../../../config.json");
let mysql      = require('mysql');

router.post("/add", function(req, res) {
    // Do Something
    res.send("added");
});

router.get("/get", function(req, res, next) {
    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host    : config.dbHost,
        user    : config.dbUser,
        password: config.dbPass
    });

    connection.connect();
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM ' + config.dbName + '.`tablename`', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(rows);
    });
    connection.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you change it this way: `app.use('/api/v1/todos/', todosRouter);` adding a trailing `/` after `todos`.

Comment: @toneyt   Change method to POST on the client side (postman etc) when you hit /add api.

Comment: @toneyt the get method for your route "add" is not defined , you must add router.get('/add',.....) before calling the the post method.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman - No change sadly. Still 404.

Comment: @toneyt GET / POST? Works for me locally.

Comment: @MukulDev - I am just opening the url in the browser. But I also just made a request in my react app with POST method and it still returned 404.

Comment: @toneyt Opening url in the browser results in a GET request.

Comment: @MukulDev - Yeah a realized that just the moment I sent that comment... Anyways, thank you guys for your help, problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the code, the issue may be because of the HTTP request method from client, use POST for `/api/v1/todos/add`. I created a sample repo with your code and added tests too, see [github source repo](https://github.com/pktippa/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/58324084) and see the [tests](https://github.com/pktippa/stackoverflow-questions/blob/master/58324084/tests/index.js) to get more clarity, especially [this POST test.](https://github.com/pktippa/stackoverflow-questions/blob/60f78c93bec98c12ad0347429c3112d6bcb0090d/58324084/tests/index.js#L21-L30)

Comment: You are right, I am having an other error in my react code. I have just created a small jquery POST request which worked fine and gave me the expected result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use GET because your add Route is POST so it is giving 404.

```
router.get("/add", function(req, res) {
    // Do Something
    res.send("added");
});
```

[image]